# Why show page with data-attribute does not work in the following context?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a class = btnshowPage and a data attribute called data-showThisPage to show relevant pages on repective button clicks throughtout the whole page. It works fine everywhere but not in the following context:
Please help me what´s wrong?

The code which connect buttons and pages:

```
// hide and show pages on button clicks with data attribute


funtion showPages() {

  var aBtnShowPages = document.getElementsByClassName( "btnShowPage" );
  // this is an array
  for ( var i = 0; i < aBtnShowPages.length; i++ ) {

      aBtnShowPages[i].addEventListener( "click", function() {
          console.log( "WORKS" ); 
          // Hide the pages
          var aPages = document.getElementsByClassName( "page" );
          for (var j = 0; j < aPages.length; j++) {
              aPages[j].style.display = "none";
          }

          var sDataAttribute = this.getAttribute( "data-showThisPage" );
          console.log( sDataAttribute );
          document.getElementById( sDataAttribute ).style.display = "flex";
      });
  }
```

and the context where it doesnt´work:

```
// DISPLAY ALL users dinamically using a loop and then INSERT into HTML

  function showUsers() {

  lblUserList.innerHTML = "";

  for ( var i = 0; i < ajUserDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

      var lblUser = document.createElement('div');
      lblUser.classList.add( "lblUser" );

      lblUser.innerHTML = '<img src="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].image + '" alt="user" class="lblUserImage" data-userImage="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<h3 class="lblUserId" data-userId"' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '">' + 'Id:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserRole" data-userRole="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].role + '">' + 'Role:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].role + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserName" data-userName="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].name + '">' + 'Name:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblUserLastName" data-userLastName="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].lastname + '">' + 'Lastname:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].lastname + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserPassword" data-userPassword="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].password + '">' + 'Password:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].password + '</h3>' + '<button id="btnEditUserBody" class="btnShowPage btnEditUser" data-userId="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '" data-showThisPage="pageUpdateUser">' + 'EDIT USER' + '</button>' + '<button class="btnDeleteUser" data-userId="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'DELETE USER' + '</button>' + '<h3 class="lblErrorMessage" id="lblDeleteUserErrorMessage">' + '</h3>';

      if ( ajUserDataFromServer[i].email ) { //if email has a value ADD email to the DIV

        var lblUserEmail = document.createElement('h3');     
        lblUserEmail.classList.add( "lblUserEmailorPhoneNumber" );
        lblUserEmail.setAttribute( "data-userEmailorPhoneNumber", ajUserDataFromServer[i].email );
        lblUserEmail.innerText =  'Email:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].email;

        lblUser.insertBefore( lblUserEmail, lblUser.children[3] );
        //parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, parentElement.children[2]);

        }

      if ( ajUserDataFromServer[i].phonenumber ) { //if pnonenumber has a value ADD phonenumber to the DIV

        var lblUserPhoneNumber = document.createElement('h3');
        lblUserPhoneNumber.classList.add( "lblUserEmailorPhoneNumber" );
        lblUserPhoneNumber.setAttribute( "data-userEmailorPhoneNumber", ajUserDataFromServer[i].phonenumber );
        lblUserPhoneNumber.innerText =  'Phone-number:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].phonenumber;

        lblUser.insertBefore( lblUserPhoneNumber, lblUser.children[3] );

        }


        lblUserList.appendChild( lblUser );


    }

}
```

the page that should be shown / html:

```
 <!-- UPDATE user for ADMIN -->
    <div id="pageUpdateUser" class="page popup">
        <div class="lblWrapper">
            <h3>UPDATE USER</h3>
            <form class="form" id="frmUpdateUser">
               <input type="hidden" id="txtUpdateUserId" name="txtUpdateUserId">
               <input type="text" id="txtUpdateUserRole" name="txtUpdateUserRole" placeholder="Role">
               <input type="text" id="txtUpdateUserEmailorPhoneNumber" name="txtUpdateUserEmailorPhoneNumber" placeholder="Mobile number or Email">
               <input type="text" id="txtUpdateUserName" name="txtUpdateUserName" placeholder="Name">
               <input type="text" id="txtUpdateUserLastName" name="txtUpdateUserLastName" placeholder="Lastname"> 
               <input type="password" id="txtUpdateUserPassword" name="txtUpdateUserPassword" placeholder="Password">
               <img id="txtUpdateUserImage" alt="UserImage">
               <div class="lblFileUpload">
                  <p>Select your picture:</p>
                  <input type="file" name="fileUserImage">
                </div>
               <button type="button" class="btnForm" id="btnUpdateUserForm">Update User</button>
            </form>
            <h3 class="lblErrorMessage" id="lblUpdateUserErrorMessage"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also wanna mention that before making some changes in the context, it worked. And was looking the following then:

```
function showUsers() {

      lblUserList.innerHTML = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < ajUserDataFromServer.length; i++) {
          //console.log("id is: "+ajUserDataFromServer[i].id);
          var lblUser = '<div class="lblUser">' + '<img src="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].image + '" alt="user" class="lblUserImage" data-userImage="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<h3 class="lblUserId">' + 'Id:' + ' ' +
              ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserRole" data-userRole="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].role + '">' + 'Role:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].role + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserName" data-userName="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].name + '">' + 'Name:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].name + '<h3 class ="lblUserLastName" data-userLastName="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].lastname + '">' + 'Lastname:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].lastname + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserEmail" data-userEmail="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].email + '">' + 'Email:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].email + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserPhoneNumber" data-userPhoneNumber="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].phonenumber + '">' + 'Phone-number:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].phonenumber + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserPassword" data-userPassword="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].password + '">' + 'Password:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].password + '</h3>' + '<button id="btnEditUserBody" class="btnShowPage btnEditUser" data-userId="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '" data-showThisPage="pageUpdateUser">' + 'EDIT USER' + '</button>' + '<button class="btnDeleteUser" data-userId="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'DELETE USER' + '</button>' + '<h3 class="lblErrorMessage" id="lblDeleteUserErrorMessage">' + '</h3>' + '</div>';

          //var lblUser = "<div>"+ajUserDataFromServer[i].id+"</div>";

          lblUserList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', lblUser);
          showPages();

      }

  }
```

However these changes are necessary as some of the users signed up with Phonenumber and some with Email, so I seperated them with the if conditions to show the relevant. So I guees is something wrong with the way is this dynamically created but I have no idea what exactly.

Comment: What does ajUserDataFromServer look like?

Comment: Your old `showUsers` function  calls `showPages();` at the end,  your new version does not

Comment: Bingo Steve. Ah my stupid mistake. Thank´s a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help you